# Root-finding algorithms for discrete function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, roots

Assume that we have function f(x)

f(x) has 3 possible constant outputs

f(x)= a if x>b

f(x)= 0   if x =b

f(x)= -a if x<b

Is there an iteration method that can be used to generate initial guess then iterates to find b?

Answer (score 0):

**For initial guess**

Take $u_1 = 0$ and $\epsilon = 1$ if $f(u_0) = -a$ / $\epsilon = -1$ if $f(u_0) = a$. Compute $u_n = u_0 + n \epsilon$ until $f(u_0)f(u_n) \lt 0$.

Then use [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) algorithm.

Comment: The question is about *initial* guesses

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If I read well the question, it has two folds... and I answered only the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $l$ and $r$ such that $f(l) = -a$ and $f(r) = a$ then the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) should converge to $x$.

That is, set $l_1 = l$ and $r_1 = r$. Then if $f\left(\frac{l_n + r_n}{2}\right) = 0$ we are done. Otherwise if it is $-a$, set $l_{n+1} = l_n$ and $r_{n+1} = \frac{l_n + r_n}{2}$ and finally if is $a$, set $l_{n+1} = \frac{l_n + r_n}{2}$ and $r_{n+1} = r_n$. $l_n$ and $r_n$ should both converge to $x$.

Now to find initial guesses, try $l = -2^n$ and $r = 2^n$ which will find initial guesses in the asymptotic order of binary digits of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain were a compact interval such as $[a,b]$, you'd simply take the boundary points as initial guesses and proceed by binary bisection. Here, we can use a suitable function to map $\Bbb R$ to a bounded interval and extend it to its closure.

For example, $\arctan$ maps $\Bbb R$ to $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, so we might do the following

1. Set $L\leftarrow-\frac \pi2$ and $R\leftarrow \frac\pi2$.
2. If $L>-\frac\pi2$ and $R<\frac\pi2$, go to step 7
3. Set $M\leftarrow \frac{L+R}2$ and compute $Y=f(\tan M)$
4. If $Y=0$, terminate with result $\tan M$
5. If $Y=a$, set $R\leftarrow M$ and go back to step 2
6. Otherwise, set $L\leftarrow M$ and go back to step 2
7. Set $L\leftarrow \tan L$, $R\leftarrow\tan R$
8. Set $M\leftarrow \frac{L+R}2$ and compute $Y=f(M)$
9. If $Y=0$, terminate with result $M$
10. If $Y=a$, set $R\leftarrow M$ and go back to step 8
11. Otherwise, set $L\leftarrow M$ and go back to step 8